# Decompose into completely stabilizer preserving channel in surface codes

Tags: pauli-gates, decoherence, surface-code, linear-algebra

[In the article "Sampling-based quasiprobability simulation for fault-tolerant quantum error correction on the surface codes under coherent noise"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.04478) they are talking about decomposing (possibly non-Clifford) noise channels into the sum of completely stabilizer preserving (CSP) channels and completely positive trace-preserving (CPTP) channels $S_{k}^{(i)}$ in formula (5) page 2.

There is also an example of it on page 3, where they decompose:

[image]

into:

[image]

### My questions:

1. What is the meaning of the definition of CSP and CPTP and how exactly to decompose into them tell me that I will get equivalent Pauli errors?
2. Given any error channel, how am I finding those channels?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "how exactly to decompose into them tell me that I will get equivalent Pauli errors?"

Comment: In the example I showed, what was the recipe to find these channels? it is from the article

Comment: The recipe would be as sketched in my answer below. But I suspect that the authors made an educated guess for this single-qubit example. It might not even be the optimal decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

First, the formulation is a bit unclear at that point. I don't know what they want to say with "and completely positive trace-reserving
(CPTP) channels". Any quantum channel is by definition CPTP.  I think what the authors want to do is to decompose the noise channel as an affine combination of CSP channels (which is always possible).

To answer your questions:

1. CSP means "completely stabilizer-preserving". A quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$ is CSP if $\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathrm{id}_n (|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$ is a convex combination of stabilizer states, for any $2n$-qubit stabilizer state $\psi$. Equivalently, the Choi state of $\mathcal{E}$ is a convex combination of $2n$-qubit stabilizer states. (see [Seddon and Campbell "Quantifying magic for multi-qubit operations"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03322))
2. The decomposition of $\mathcal E$ into CSP channels is not unique. You want the decomposition
   $$
    \mathcal E = \sum_k c_k S_k
   $$
   for which $\sum_k |c_k|$ is minimal. This is called the *channel robustness* $R_*(\mathcal E)$.
   In principal, you can compute the optimal decomposition using a linear program (in practice, you can only solve that for up to 2-3 qubits). For more details, see again the above paper and also [Howard and Campbell "Application of a Resource Theory for Magic States to Fault-Tolerant Quantum Computing"](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.090501) and [Heinrich and Gross "Robustness of Magic and Symmetries of the Stabiliser Polytope"](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2019-04-08-132/).

Comment: about CPTP- Notice that it is collapsing bigger space into its subpace after measure ancillas. and for the operation to be mathematically decompose correctly, so you make sure they are CPTP.

Comment: So I understand this decomposing is not trivial at all, and has a big run time? What is the complexity of this decompostion?

Comment: And, if it so difficult, how did they do it in the article for such big surface code? It seems like the docmposition was done only for 1 qubit?

Comment: and , you also told me just how to find $c_k$ I am interested in how to find the $S_k$ of the channel, before I find $c_k$

Comment: @RonCohen sure if you use quantum channels, you have to make sure that they are CPTP ... that's the pleonasm I mentioned. Anyway, not important for the whole story.

Comment: @RonCohen finding the *optimal* decomposition is not trivial. The runtime is $2^{O(n^2)}$ which explodes heavily beyond $n=2$ qubits. Finding the *optimal* decomposition minimizes the *runtime* of the subsequent simulation. Note that the runtime of the simulation might be much faster! Moreover, having found the decomposition, you can re-use it as often as you want: anytime you want to run a simulation invoking said channel. Finally, you can also simulate with sub-optimal decompositions at the cost of increased simulation runtime (they might be simpler to find!).

Comment: @RonCohen A decomposition is a set of pairs $(c_k, S_k)$. You compute both and you will need both for the simulation!

Comment: How is it done? what are the degress of freedom when you run your algorithm? How do you model the $S_k$?

Comment: @RonCohen You have the perform a $\ell_1$ minimization of the coefficients $(c_k)$ subject to the constraint $\mathcal E = \sum_k c_k S_k$. That can be rewritten as a linear program and solved with standard solvers. Modelling the $S_k$ is complicated since you have to intersect the stabilizer polytope in the Choi picture with the additional TP condition. Interstead, you can add the TP condition as a constraint to the program. Again, details can be found in the "Quantifying magic" paper.